# Adding new page to Admin Panel in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am developing an e-commerce website and I need to customize the database. I want to add some tables into the database and records entry should be done from the Magento Admin Panel, eg:-

Like as we click Add New Product under Manage Products from Magento Admin Panel, whatever data we provide there like, name, weight, description, sku, etc, it is entered to the respective database table automatically.

Now, let’s say I want three more tables to be created in the database: Brand(brand_id, brand_name, brand_desc...), Brand_loc(brand_id, brand_loc_id, brand_address, brand_city, brand_state...), Product(prod_id, brand_id, brand_loc_id, prod_name, prod_weight....). 
So, I want the above tables’ attributes to be shown in Magento Admin Panel and as I enter the data from Magento Admin Panel, it should be entered to the respective tables in the database like I explained of Add New Product above.

Can anyone please help me on the above issue....

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will proceed as follows :

1. add a event observer in my module so that can be called once a product is saved, there are various observers in magento for before and after events.
2. when a product is saved i will add my code of saving data into custom tables in the observer function.

tutorial to add product after observer is here :

http://snipplr.com/view/56959/

As per a magento developer i would advice to create a complete module doing as said above, and also create pages so that admin can edit/delete brands in your case.

Comment: Yes, I have created module for this functionality. I will follow the steps and check it out. How will I get the same view as that of page when we press "add new product" button.

Comment: have you listen about module creator for magento, http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modulecreator.html.. this will create a complete new module that can be used for further edits... also this will create a admin view where you can add/edit/delete the rows.. check it pout.. it help as a starting point in development of module later you can also add an observer to the same.

Comment: @Jenny it would be glad for me to just vote up our answer so someone can use in future if they have similar issue

Comment: magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modulecreator.html. did wonder. I would suggest you to go for it. It creates a fulfilled module